# Android: delaying toast

Tags: android, delay, toast

How can i delay a toast? like 15-60 seconds? Here's my code:

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                boolean split = false;

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)   
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Message sent!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // sendSMS(phoneNo, message, split);  
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }
```

How should i implement the delay?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayedms);
```

put the toast in your runnable.

or

AlaramManager.

Comment: should i put if-else conditions/switch conditions for the time delay chosen by the user? because the user chooses from 15, 30, 60 seconds and no delay

Comment: take a time variable and set it to what user chooses, and multiply by 1000 and give it to delayed time.

Comment: The user chooses from the spinner, how can i get the value of the chosen time delay of the user? can you give me any example?